# Python script to fill a simple html form using mechanize

Tags: python, html, mechanize

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert Data into DB</title>
</head>
<body>


<hl><br>Insert Data into DB</hl>

<form method="post" action="" name="form1">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Slot Status</legend>
    <label>slot:<input type="text" name="fname" /></label>
    <label>status:<input type="text" name="lname" /></label>
</fieldset>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Slot Status" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Sir above is a simple html form I made and i want to fill this form using python Script.Especially I want to use the mechanize module. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms_api.html

Comment: Sir I need a python script which will fill the above html form and submit it. I wanted that it should be done using mechanize module of python.Please any solution

Comment: Follow the tutorial

Comment: @SuperCoolBucket, hello there, What I know, For easy use of python for web development you will need an MVC framework(eg. Flask, Django) they have libraries that will help you place data and do some python logic in html files. checkout: [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

Comment: This is a bad question because you're not asking a specific question. That said, the above comments are bad comments because rather than point this out, they say rtfm. Which there isn't really one because python mechanize is a terrible abandoned project. I guess what I'm trying to say is: Use requests or find another language to do this in.

Comment: As another commenter said, don't use mechanize.  If you want to execute javascript, i.e., fill forms, click buttons, etc, check out Selenium. If you just want to POST data, the python requests module is probably sufficient.

Comment: Sir Below I am giving the link of the very simple html form :  http://ec2-18-221-3-22.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/new.php                                                                            Now can you plz tell me how to fill this form using request module of python? Please note that we can put slot from 1 to 6. Now after entering the slot and status you can check updated values in below link :   http://ec2-18-221-3-22.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/smartconnect.php